# Icon Font Accessibility: parent span with aria-label or sibling span with sr-only

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, icon-fonts

I have a icon which is not decorative, and it is not directly within an interactive element, though there is an interactive element in the hierarchy.

Something like this:

```
<button type="button">
    <div> Some info </div>
    <div> other info </div>
    <i class="material-icons"> icon </i>
</button>
```

This icon displays information about the status of this item.

To make it more accessible, is it better to change the structure to this:

```
<button type="button">
    <div> Some info </div>
    <div> other info </div>
    <span aria-label="the actual status">/
     <i class="material-icons"> icon </i>
    </span>
</button>
```

OR this:

```
<button type="button">
    <div> Some info </div>
    <div> other info </div>
    <i class="material-icons"> icon </i>
    <span class="sr-only"> the actual status </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Maybe someone knows this but here I would suggest that you download [this free, open source screen reader](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) and try what's getting read to the user. The best solution is the one where the context can be understood best.

Comment: To make icons **accessible to humans with dyslexia**, you should avoid using icon fonts. The often overwrite default fonts with their optimized fonts, hence they will completely lose the icon font. Use SVG icons instead. https://github.blog/2016-02-22-delivering-octicons-with-svg/#accessibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a icon which is...not directly within an interactive element

That's not what your code example shows.

```
<button>
   <i>
</button>
```

Your icon is definitely contained within an interactive element.  When a screen reader user tabs to the button, **all** the text contained between the <button> element will be read as the name of the button.  So you'll hear *"some info other info icon, button"*.

You *could* put an `aria-label` on the button but I don't like to do that because it duplicates text.

```
<button type="button" aria-label="some info other info actual status">
    <div> Some info </div>
    <div> other info </div>
    <i class="material-icons"> icon </i>
</button>
```

If you happen to change `<div>other info</div>` to `<div>some other info</div>`, you'd have to remember to change the `aria-label` to match.

Your suggestion to put an `aria-label` on the `<span>` might feel like the right thing to do but you can't stick an `aria-label` on just any element (although `aria-label` **is** a global attribute) because the element needs a "role" as well.  See "[Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)".

So your last solution is typically how icon fonts are handled, provided you also "hide" the icon from the screen reader with `aria-hidden="true"`.

```
<button type="button">
    <div> Some info </div>
    <div> other info </div>
    <i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true"> icon </i>
    <span class="sr-only"> the actual status </span>
</button>
```